# С чего лучше начать учить Assembler?

Tags: ассемблер

Меня посетила идея выучить ассемблер 
Не могли бы вы мне подсказать с чего лучше его начать учить 
Может есть какие нибудь видео курсы, книги, ролики на ютубе

Comment: Какой именно ассемблер и для чего? Сейчас на ассемблере как на таковом уже мало что пишут

Comment: В смысле какой?  Я думал он как и C++ и C# в одном "экземпляре"

Comment: Просто мне интересно выучит новые технологии  ну в данном случае технологии "древней цивилизации"

Comment: есть ассемблер x86, x64, arm - по архитектуре процессоров, есть masm, nasm, fasm и пр - с разным синтаксисом и поддержкой. Assembler - код машинный под конкретную машину (архитектуру)

Comment: @Artur ассемблер под каждое устройство свой и отличается набором инструкций и адресацией, проще для изучения будет взять какой нибудь ассемблер для 8086 и от него плясать.

Comment: @Artur , например, если писать ассемблерные вставки в visual c++, надо знать masm, для gcc - at&t и тд

Comment: Возможно если я расскажу с чего я решил его учить будет понятнее какой использовать. В крации я поступаю на пк безопасность и решил начать заранее. Я шарил в инете по моему вопросу и заметил фразу "знание ассемблера". А вот какой я не знаю честно

Comment: _В крации_ - начните с изучения русского языка.

Comment: Во первых мы не на экзамене русского языка. Во вторых как говориться Т9 не прикажешь

Comment: @Artur, для начала посмотрите любой. В принципе, все они (ассемблеры) достаточно похожи. Естественно, в любой системе команд есть свои нюансы, но это уже скорее относится именно к ISA (Instruction Set Architecture), чем к ассемблеру, как языку символьного представления ISA